# How to aggregate annotated related objects

Tags: django, django-orm

How to calculate quantity_released from OrderedProduct?

I cant just `self.product_reservation.aggregate(total=Sum('quantity_released'))` because you cant aggregate functions or even properties. I have tried extra and subqueries with annottation, but cant make it.

```
class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    ...
    quantity_ordered = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    # TODO 
    def quantity_released(self):
        return self.product_reservations.all()
```

```
class ProductReservation(models.Model):
    ...
    order_product = models.ForeignKey("documents.OrderProduct", related_name='product_reservations' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    product_release = models.ManyToManyField("documents.ProductRelease", related_name='products_reservation', blank=True)

    def quantity_released(self):
        return self.product_release.all().aggregate(total=Sum('quantity'))['total']
```

```
class ProductRelease(models.Model):
    ...
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

*PS: If I have typed too inaccurate title then please edit it as I don't know how to phrase it better. Thank you.*

Comment: Have you tried `.annotate(count=Count("product_reservations")).aggregate(total=Sum("count"))` ?

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work + I dont need count but aggregated, annotated value.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a day of reading and searching for the answer to this question - I did it, and in the process learned a lot of things. No need to use any subquery, Q, F, Case, When, etc. Just had to give double underscore lookup to foreign key. That's it.

```
def quantity_released(self):
    return self.product_reservations.all().aggregate(total=Sum('product_release__quantity'))['total']
```